# Nested Array: How to use && operator properly to skip some loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get an "hourglass" array out from a nested array.

Say that this array is

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
```

I have to get this "hourglass" array out and add it all up:

```
1 1 1
  1
1 1 1
```

Therefore, here's my attempt:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if ((i === 1 && j === 0) && (i === 1 && j === 2)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            newArr.push(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that if I use this condition: `i === 1 && j === 0`, it was able to skip over the position at `i = 1` and `j = 0` but when I added `j = 2`, I couldn't get it to skip over the first and third positions. Therefore, I was trying out various options to get it to work but I couldn't get it to work. Such, I was wondering if I'm doing the `&& operator` correctly?

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: This `if((i === 1 && j === 0) && (i === 1 && j === 2))` means j must be 0 AND 2 wich will never be true. I think you are  looking for the OR operator `if((i === 1 && j === 0) || (i === 1 && j === 2))`

Comment: get rid of zeros and print the array.

Comment: please add the array, you are talking about. btw, you are comparing indices, not values.

Comment: guess it's a 3*6 matrix

Comment: I'd check the values, *not* the indexes - this way your code will work for any 'shape' of '1's. The answer below looks pretty good.

Comment: Do you need only that particular shape in a 3x3 size? If yes, you can just hardcode the indices and maybe omit the loop completely - doesn't matter. If you need to support more sizes, please show us some more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

To find **every hourglass** in this grid **3 rows 6 columns** grid with only **one loop** 
**Notice**: When the Grid becomes larger you have to use an inner for loop

```js
    const arr = [
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      ]  
       // format is [row][column]  
       let result;
       let topp;
       let mid;
       let bottom;
       for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      
               // this ist the filter defining what we are looking for
           if (arr[0][i] === 1 && arr[0][i+1] === 1 && arr[0][i + 2] === 1 &&
               arr[1][i] === 0 && arr[1][i+1] === 1 && arr[1][i + 2] === 0 &&
               arr[2][i] === 1 && arr[2][i+1] === 1 && arr[2][i + 2] === 1) {
               
              // here we build the string        
               topp = arr[0][i] +  " " + arr[0][i+1] + " " + arr[0][i+2];
               mid = arr[1][i] + " " + arr[1][i+1] + " " + arr[1][i+2];
               bottom = arr[2][i] + " " + arr[2][i+1] + " " + arr[2][i + 2];
       
               result = topp + "\n" + mid + "\n" + bottom;
               
           }
       }
       console.log(result)
```

Comment: put yourself into the perspective of the reader of that code

Comment: Umm, the indizes correspond to the row column format. I dont think its so hard to understand especially with top mid bottom variable before calculating the sum...

Comment: do you need the difference between JS and Java?

Comment: please tell me :)

Comment: Umm.... the keyword are JavaScript. I'm not familiar with Java. Also in the if condition, is it looking by Boolean method?

Comment: @KristinaBressler I've updated it. Sorry I'm also more familiar with JavaScript. But for a weird reason I thought we are talking about Java :D

Comment: @Alex It's okay. I was able to somehow understand the Java code and converted it to JavaScript code and made some modifications. I'm now figuring out finding hourglass vertical in 6x6 grid. My original question was actually about the && operator, but I used your suggestions to modified my code in different way since I haven't thought about this possibility. There's really lots of ways to solve a javascript challenge.

Comment: On Hackkerrank (it's like leetcode) there are some programming challenges I had a challenge to find the hourglass with the highest sum in an 6x6 grid. This was also really interesting.

Comment: I just solved this 6x6 grid challenge on HackerRank thanks to your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You could add spaces for the zeros (0) and for the ones (1) or maybe any other number just accumulate them;

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
]
let printRow = '';
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    if (arr[i][j] === 0) {
      printRow += ' ';
    } else {
      printRow += arr[i][j];
    }
  }
  console.log(printRow);
  printRow = '';
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, is it related to the numbers itself in the array or to the positions? What if the array are different like this?
`-9 -9 -9  1 1 1     
 2 -9  4  4 3 2      
-9 -9 -9  1 2 3`
That's why I need to look by positions/indexs.